# Latent semantic analysis (LSA) single value decomposition (SVD) understanding

Tags: analysis, svd, latent-semantic-indexing, latent-semantic-analysis

Bear with me through my modest understanding of LSI (Mechanical Engineering background):

After performing SVD in LSI, you have 3 matrices:

U, S, and V transpose.

U compares words with topics and S is a sort of measure of strength of each feature. Vt compares topics with documents.

```
 U dot S dot Vt
```

returns the original matrix before SVD. Without doing too much (none) in-depth algebra it seems that:

```
 U dot S dot **Ut**
```

returns a term by term matrix, which provides a comparison between the terms. i.e. how related one term is to other terms, a DSM (design structure matrix) of sorts that compares words instead of components. I could be completely wrong,  but I tried it on a sample data set, and the results seemed to make sense. It could just be bias though (I wanted it to work, so I saw what I wanted).  I can't post the results as the documents are protected.

My question though is: Does this make any sense? Logically? Mathematically?

Thanks for any time/responses.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know how related one term is to another you can just compute

> > > (U dot S)

The terms are represented by the row vectors. You can then compute the distance matrix by applying a distance function such as euclidean distance. Once you make the distance matrix by computing the distance between all the vectors the resulted matrix should be hollow symmetric with all distances >0. if the distance A[i,j] is small then they are related otherwise they are not.